# OCaml - parsing nodes at level in tree

Tags: tree, ocaml

I would like to write all nodes on the level to list.

```
type 'a tree = T of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;;

 let at_level t lvl=
      let rec aux t k =
         match t with
        |Leaf -> []
        |T(x, l, r) -> if k = lvl then 
           (x::aux l (k+1)) @ (aux r (k+1))
        else 
        (aux l (k+1)) @( aux r (k+1))
      in aux t lvl;;
```

But I always receive the result: [x] where x is value of root.
Where is the problem in my program  ?

Comment: hint: Breadth First Search

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling `aux t lvl` when you should be calling `aux t 0`, otherwise you'll always have `k = lvl` from the start (i.e. at the root of the tree).

Also, why do you call `aux l (k+1)` when you've already found the correct level ? The `k = lvl` equality can't possibly be true afterwards.

Anyway, here's the code with a few formatting changes :

```
type 'a tree = T of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree | Leaf;;

let at_level tree lvl =                                       
  let rec aux t k = match t with                                
    |Leaf -> []                                                   
    |T(value, left, right) when k = lvl -> [value]                
    |T(value, left, right) -> (aux left (k+1)) @ (aux right (k+1))
  in aux tree 0;;


# let tree = T(5,T(6,Leaf,Leaf),T(7,Leaf,Leaf));;
# at_level tree 1;;
- : int list = [6; 7]
```